# ORACLE - SQL - select from table at least subset of data searched for an agent

Tags: sql, subset

I have a problem (ORACLE):

**Table**:

user_agency
id
agent_id
agency_id

I am trying to find all agents which contains at least the same subset of data like a searched users.

My sql:

```
select ua.agent_id from user_agency ua where agency_id in (
select agency_id from user_agency where agent_id = 123
) and ua.agent_id != 123
```

It works fine when users have 1 agency but in situation when searched user has more than 1 agency, it will still return agents which shouldn't be returned.

**In example:**

*user1:*
agency1, agency2, agency3

*user2:*
    agency1

If I search for  user1 - I would expect that it will not return any users in this case.

**Situation2:**

*user1:* 
    agency1, agency2
*user2:* 
    agency1, agency2, agency3, agency4
*user3:*
        agency2

I expect that if I search for user1 it will return user2 because user2 contains at least the same agencies like user1 but it will not return user3 because he doesn't have agency1.

Any thoughts, ideas?

--EDIT the fiddle example table (thank you hd1 for the suggestion)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f9d/6/0

Comment: Would you please show some evidence of effort, preferably, in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a negation logic to achieve this and it works with your sample data.

```
select distinct
    agent_id
from
   user_agency 
where
   -- all other than the given agent
   agent_id <> 3
   and agent_id not in 
   (
     select
        uaTarget.agent_id
     from
        user_agency uaSource
        inner join user_agency uaTarget on
        uaSource.agent_id <> uaTarget.agent_id
     where
        -- given agent
        uaSource.agent_id = 3
        and not exists 
           (select agency_id 
            from user_agency 
            where
            agent_id = uaTarget.agent_id
            and agency_id = uaSource.agency_id)
  )
```

Please see the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f9d/38)